# Why my Angular Material Styles Not Working Correctly?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I tried to design angular web application.so I use angular material but It Styles Not working correctly.
I set other things correctly But I can't understand this issue!

[Error Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RljMb.png)

[Error Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG6T2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the required imports for theming and also the material modules that you are using like

```
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

and add to imports array of your feature module or a shared module

Comment: I do it too. Error is still my project

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you miss style of material. You can try add `@import '~@angular/material/theming';` into file stlye. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Follow https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started for complete flow of Angular Material installation.

As per your error screenshots it seems some extra stylesheets are affecting the existing one, this may be due to the file **style.scss** file. Please check this file for any additional styles and remove them.

Comment: I checked !  But additional styles are not there